# Как использовать псевдокласс :hover, svg с несколькими <path>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Имеется svg иконка, состоящая из нескольких , как возможно реализовать смену цвета(hover), при наведении в ее область.

```html
<a class="socials__link socials__link_inst" href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 169.063 169.063" style="enable-background:new 0 0 169.063 169.063;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path class="hvs" d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752   c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407   c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752   c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path class="hvs" d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561   C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561   c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path class="hvs" d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78   c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78   C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.socials__link:hover path{
  fill:red;
}
```

```css
a.socials__link path {
  transition:1s;
}

a.socials__link:hover path{
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<a class="socials__link socials__link_inst" href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 169.063 169.063" style="enable-background:new 0 0 169.063 169.063;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path id="hvs" d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752   c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407   c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752   c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path id="hvs" d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561   C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561   c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path id="hvs" d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78   c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78   C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Достаточно написать svg:hover path и всё

```css
svg:hover path{
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 169.063 169.063" style="enable-background:new 0 0 169.063 169.063;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path style="fill:black" id="hvs" d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752   c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407   c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752   c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path style="fill:black" id="hvs" d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561   C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561   c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
     <path style="fill:black" id="hvs" d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78   c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78   C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT восстановил справедливость

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Использование переменных

```css
svg {
--f:dodgerblue;
}
svg:hover path {
 fill: var(--f);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 169.063 169.063" style="enable-background:new 0 0 169.063 169.063;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path fill="black" class="hvs" d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752   c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407   c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752   c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z" fill="black"/>
     <path fill="black" class="hvs" d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561   C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561   c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z" />
     <path fill="black" class="hvs" d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78   c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78   C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z" />
    </g>
    </svg>
```

*Когда svg файл добавляется извне, то невозможно изменить его окраску обычными правилами CSS (:hover)*

Но есть способы перекрасить изображение и в этом случае:

### 2. Javascript

В примере ниже используется фильтр `filter:hue-rotate`

```js
img.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
  img.style.cssText = "filter:hue-rotate(170deg);cursor:pointer; transform:scale(1.2);"
}) 
img.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
  img.style.cssText = "filter:hue-rotate(0deg);cursor:pointer;"
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <img id="img" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f431.svg" style="cursor:pointer" width="200" height="200" />

  </div>
```

### 3. Фильтры SVG или CSS

В примере ниже использованы два фильтра `<feFlood flood-color` c разным цветом для реализации эффекта наведения

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


img {
  filter: url(#filter_B);
}
img:hover {
  filter: url(#filter_G);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img id="img" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f532.svg" style="cursor:pointer" width="200" height="200" >
</div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">  
    <defs>
       <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_G">
         <feFlood flood-color="yellowgreen"/>
         <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
      </filter>   
        <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_B">
           <feFlood flood-color="dodgerblue"/>
           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```